# Is it possible to use the Tableau developer API to serve interactive Tableau visualizations to remote systems without making it public?

Tags: tableau-api

I am wondering if there is a way using one of the developer APIs / tools for Tableau to embed interactive Tableau Visualizations in a web application without making the Tableau server either:

A) A publicly hosted server (not Tableau public) or

B) using Tableau public

Essentially the web application (which is public) would be the intermediary between the Tableau server and the client.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: You're going to want what is called the JavaScript API - https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm

Comment: The server would still have to be hosted publicly in order to use the Javascript API though

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your dashboard in tableau public and use javascript API to embed in a web app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Tableau public due to the data being sensitive.

Comment: You can also hide your dashboard from public view but you have to secure your public link. If the data are sensitive then you have to use tableau server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you tableau server will have to be on internet but it need not open to login by public.
The system works similar to what you described, web application (which is public) would be the intermediary between the Tableau server and the client.

You can set up 'trusted authentication' between the server hosting the web application and tableau server.
When users open the web application, the web application server authenticates itself with tableau server. Using this authentication token, it gets the vizualisation and loads it in user's browser inside a special div or iframe which is embedded in the rest of the web application.

You can see more details about trusted authentication [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm)